# Gradle not working after fresh new install on debian linux

Tags: gradle, debian

I just installed gradle on debian using the `sudo apt-get install gradle` command. When i try to run gralde afterwards it throws the following stack trace :

```
 org.gradle.api.internal.classpath.UnknownModuleException: Cannot
 locate JAR for module 'ant' in distribution directory 'null'.
         at org.gradle.api.internal.classpath.DefaultModuleRegistry.findExternalJar(DefaultModuleRegistry.java:242)
         at org.gradle.api.internal.classpath.DefaultModuleRegistry.getExternalModule(DefaultModuleRegistry.java:101)
         at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultClassPathProvider.findClassPath(DefaultClassPathProvider.java:46)
         at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultClassPathRegistry.getClassPath(DefaultClassPathRegistry.java:34)
         at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:43)
         at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:32)
         at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:26)
```

`Gradle` by default gets installed into

```
/usr/share/gradle
```

I have all the jars gradle requires in my jdk, so is there any way to tell gradle to search for the libraries there and start to work ?

Comment: Your gradle build is looking for ant jar, and it's not finding it. Add an entry for ant jar in you build.gradle file, hope it will work.

Comment: @Arpit that's a red herring, the issue is related to the gradle distribution path.  You can change the behaviour by altering the `GRADLE_USER_HOME` environment variable, but that doesn't explain why it works with one distribution directory and not another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set your GRADLE_HOME

export GRADLE_HOME=/usr/share/gradle

Is there a lib under that directory?  It should have the ant jar.

Comment: You might get more success with `GRADLE_USER_HOME`

Comment: I have the lib under that directory but I don't have the ant.jar